# Jacobian of Identity?

Tags: jacobian

[image]
If one does the substitution as mentioned here, the left side will be Jacobian of an identity map isn’t it? How to compute that and how to conclude that the Jacobian here is invertible.

Comment: In the identity, $u(x,y)=x$ and $v(x,y)=y$ etc.

Comment: In the left hand side we have Jacobian of phi and it’s inverse. What happens in this case?

Comment: Look at the formula for $J(\Psi)$: substitute in $u(x,y)=x$ and $v(x,y)=y$.

Comment: The Jacobian of any linear map is just the matrix that represents that map.